# I want to refresh partially the Cart details page using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I am missing something to be able to properly update the page after I clicked Remove from Cart.
Actually the item has been removed from the cart table but it still showing up on the screen.

I am missing a command to refresh partially the screen after my jquery has been executed.

Thanks for your solution.

Ex. of the output right now

```
 Cart Summary:

 Payment >>
    ----------

 Baseball Glove item has been removed from your shopping cart.

 Product        Price Quantity
 Baseball Glove 34.99 1            Remove from Cart
                                   ----------------
 Total                             0
```

Ex. of the output i will like to have

```
 Cart Summary:

 Payment >>
 ----------

 Baseball Glove item has been removed from your shopping cart.

 Product        Price Quantity

 Total                             0
```

Index.cshtml  view from Panier

```
 @model Tp1WebStore3.ViewModels.ShoppingCartViewModel

 @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Shopping Cart";
 }
 <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
         $('.RemoveLink').click(function () {
             $.ajax({
                 url: '@Url.Action("RemoveFromCart","Panier")',
                 data: { id: $(this).data('id') },
                 type: 'POST',
                 cache: false,
                 success: function (result) {
                    $('#row-' + result.DeleteId).remove();
                    $('#row-' + result.DeleteId).fadeOut('slow');
                    $('#cart-status').text('Cart (' + result.CartCount + ')');
                    $('#update-message').text(result.Message);
                    $('#cart-total').text(result.CartTotal);
                    $.get('@Url.Action("CartSummary", "Panier")');
             },
             error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
             alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
         }
     });
     return false;
    });
 });
 </script>

 <h3>
     <em>Details</em> du panier:
 </h3>
 <p class="button">
     @Html.ActionLink("Paiement >>", "AddressAndPayment", "Checkout")
 </p>  
 <div id="update-message">
 </div>
 <table>
     <tr>
         <th>
             Produit
         </th>
         <th>
             Prix (unitaire)
         </th>
         <th>
             Quantite
         </th>
         <th></th>
     </tr>


     @foreach (var item in Model.CartItems)
     {
         <tr id="row-@item.ProduitId">
             <td>
                 @Html.ActionLink(item.Produit.Description, "Details", "Produit", new { id = 
                        item.ProduitId }, null)
             </td>
             <td>
                 @item.Produit.Prix
             </td>
             <td id="item-count-@item.PanierId">
                 @item.Quantite
             </td>
             <td>
                 <a href="#" class="RemoveLink" data-id="@item.PanierId"> Enlever du panier </a>
             </td>
         </tr>
     }


     <tr>
         <td>
             Total
         </td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td id="cart-total">
             @Model.CartTotal
         </td>
     </tr>

 </table>
```

I have tried window.location.reload(); but this is fully reload the page.  I guess I just need a partial refresh of the page.  Any hint ?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to put your Product table (the part under the update message) in a partial view, and render that view in a specific action. In the main view, replace the table with an identified div (`<div id="products"></div>` for example)
Once the Ajax call from the RemoveLink is finished, call that action and make it so that the #products div is refreshed.

```
url = '@Url.Action("_DisplayProducts", CONTROLLER_NAME)';
        $.get(url, function (data) {
            $("#products").html(data);
        })
```

---

Edit after the comments : This is the ajax call

```
url = '@Url.Action("_DisplayProducts", CONTROLLER_NAME)'?cartId=@Model.YOUR_ID;
        $.get(url, function (data) {
            $("#products").html(data);
        })
```

Here is the action that you can use

```
public ActionResult _DisplayProducts(string cartId)
{
ShoppingCartViewModel cart = GetShoppingCart(cartId);
return View("_DisplayProducts", cart);
}
```

Comment: When I do this I got an error of   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.   at the @foreach (var item in Model.CartItems)

Comment: Yeah, I forgot about the reference to the ShoppingCartViewModel.  
Change the url to '@Url.Action("_DisplayProducts", CONTROLLER_NAME)'?cartId=@Model.YOUR_ID
In the _DisplayProducts, fetch the viewmodel corresponding to the id
`public ActionResult _DisplayProducts(string cartId)
{
ShoppingCartViewModel cart = GetShoppingCart(cartId);
return View("_DisplayProducts", cart);
}`
That should be better. Maybe not the cleanest way to do it, but that's all my ill brain can get now :)

Comment: can you update your answer so I can be sure I am doing the right test and then I can approve your answer? thanks